# ASP.NET MVC Prevent Action Redirection with AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an AJAX function inside of my `_Layout.cshtml` partial view that's used by all views that posts to `SignIn()`. If the login is unsuccessful, it is supposed to redirect to `SignInFailed()` and simply return the view. Instead, after returning the view, it is redirecting back to the original view.

I am not receiving any kind of exceptions or errors that would prevent it from remaining in `SignInFailed()`.

Here is my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           traditional: true,
           url: "@Url.Action("SignIn", "Home")",
           data: { user: name, password: code, pageName: urlPage },
                   success: function () {
                       ///do stuff
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if (debug) {
                            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                            alert(textStatus);
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    }
});
```

Why is it redirecting back to the original view when there is no instruction to do so and what can I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Its not _redirecting back to the original view_. Its an ajax call and ajax calls never redirect - you never left the page. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see. Even if I set the action to ```return RedirectToAction``` will it still remain on the same page?

Comment: Yes. (that's the whole purpose of ajax)

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can I use JavaScript to post data and still redirect? I can't post using razor and models because the sign in form is shared across all views including views with their own form (like a contact page).

Comment: You can return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise, and based on that, use `location.href = someUrl;` in the success callback to redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Aweseome! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke says in the comments of my question, AJAX is designed to post and get data without refreshing or redirecting the page; hence why my previous method didn't work. Instead of trying to redirect in the back-end, I return JSON from the back-end letting the front-end know whether login was successful. Then, depending on the result, I redirect or refresh with JavaScript.

I changed my `SignIn()` action to return JSON:

```
public ActionResult SignIn(string user, string password)
{
    //Some database stuff validating username and password
    if (loginSuccessful)
    {
        return Json(new { status = "success" });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { status = "failure", redirectUrl = "/Home/SignInFailed" });
    }

}
```

and I changed my AJAX to:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           traditional: true,
           url: "@Url.Action("SignIn", "Home")",
           data: { user: name, password: code },
                   success: function (result) {

                       if (result.status == "success") {
                           location.reload();
                       }
                       else {
                           location.href = result.redirectUrl;
                       }
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if (debug) {
                            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                            alert(textStatus);
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    }
});
```